# How to remove a cookie in Apache

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, apache2

I need to remove a cookie from the HTTP request that gets to the server. Doing it on the client (that writes this cookie) or on the server (that reads it) is not an option. I have Apache 2.0 that proxies requests between client and the server, so I was hoping to remove the cookie right there in Apache using mod_rewrite.

My question is, is there a way to remove a certain cookie from the HTTP request using mod_rewrite?

If not possible to remove just *one* cookie then as a last resort to remove *all* cookies from the request?

I am open to other suggestions of how to accomplish this if mod_rewrite is not the right tool for this task.

Comment: you can rewrite cookies using mod_rewrite using the CO flag

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Apache `mod_rewrite` allows manipulation of URLs but not of HTTP headers, however ['mod_headers'](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_headers.html) will let you do that.

So, you could use:

```
RequestHeader unset Cookie
```

This will strip *all* cookies from the request. I'm not sure if its possible to remove just a particular cookie using this technique.

Alternatively, you can stop cookies being passed back to the client using:

```
Header unset Set-Cookie
```

if that's more appropriate.

Comment: It is possible to set cookies with mod\_rewrite. But as far as I know only for the response to the client.

Answer (score 12):

With Apache > 2.2.4, [you could have used](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_headers.html#RequestHeader) :

```
RequestHeader edit Cookie "^(.*?)ANY_COOKIE=.*?;(.*)$" $1$2
```

Comment: This: `RequestHeader edit Cookie "^(.*?)ssosession=.*?(?:$|;)(.*)$" $1$2` works even if the header does not end with a `;`.

Comment: `RequestHeader edit cookie ANY_COOKIE=[^;]*?($|;) ""` should also work: this way you don't have to capture the prefix/postfix parts and put them back.

Answer (score 10):

You can manage specific cookies using following statements in apache reverse proxy configurations:

To remove any specific cookie you can use:
'**Header add Set-Cookie "ANY_COOKIE='';expires='SOME_DATE_IN_PAST'; Max-Age=0; Path=COOKIE_PATH"**'

By specifying past date, you tell the browser that the cookie has expired and browser will discard the cookie.

To add any cookie you can use:
'**Header add Set-Cookie "ANY_COOKIE='ANY_VALUE';expires='SOME_FUTURE_DATE'; Path=COOKIE_PATH"**'

Be sure that you specify the some future date. If you do not specify any date, the cookie will be treated as session cookie.

Try using the following to remove specific cookie from request:

**'RequestHeader add Cookie "ANY_COOKIE='';expires='SOME_PAST_DATE'; Path=COOKIE_PATH"'**

Comment: Try using the following to remove specific cookie from request:  **'RequestHeader add Cookie "ANY_COOKIE='';expires='SOME_PAST_DATE'; Path=COOKIE_PATH"'**

Comment: I think RequestHeader add Cookie will actually create 3 cookies for you. (ANY_COOKIE, expired and Path) which might not be what you want.

Answer (score 2):

I use this to unset all cookies (good to serve static content)

```
Header unset Cookie
Header unset Set-Cookie
```