# How to remove a specific cookie in Tomcat?

Tags: apache, tomcat, cookies, reverse-proxy

In my Tomcat 7 (bundled with my Ubuntu 12.04 LTS server), I've installed an instance of [Jasig CAS](http://www.jasig.org/cas) 3.5.1.

The problem is that in a specific case, some client browsers arrive to my CAS with a Google Analytics cookie containing accented characters :

```
Cookie: __utma=138551020.224991009.1377788460.1385030099.1385031617.283; __utmb=138551020.3.10.1385031617; __utmc=137551020; __utmz=137551020.1385931617.283.104.utmcsr=YMLP|utmccn=Coup%20de%20théatre|utmcmd=email|utmctr=mmp4_TestOctobre2013.png
```

And in that case, Tomcat doesn't manage to handle it !

```
Nov 21, 2013 1:35:41 PM org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpAprProcessor process
SEVERE: Error processing request
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Control character in cookie value or attribute.
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.CookieSupport.isHttpSeparator(CookieSupport.java:193)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.Cookies.getTokenEndPosition(Cookies.java:502)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.Cookies.processCookieHeader(Cookies.java:291)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.Cookies.processCookies(Cookies.java:168)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.Cookies.getCookieCount(Cookies.java:106)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.parseSessionCookiesId(CoyoteAdapter.java:919)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.postParseRequest(CoyoteAdapter.java:688)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:402)
        at org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpAprProcessor.process(AjpAprProcessor.java:197)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:579)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketWithOptionsProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:1763)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1146)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
```

I'm using Apache 2 (bundled in Ubuntu) to proxify requests with that configuration :

```
ProxyPass /cas ajp://localhost:8009/cas
ProxyPassReverse /cas https://sso.mycompany.com/cas
```

The question is : **could I remove that specific accented Cookie value with Apache before sending the request to Tomcat?**

(I've seen [in the sources](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.tomcat.embed/tomcat-embed-core/7.0.26/org/apache/tomcat/util/http/CookieSupport.java#CookieSupport.isHttpSeparator%28char%29) that there is no way to tell Tomcat "don't bother with control character, parse my cookie anyway")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [said here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20123361/535203), use [mod_headers](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_headers.html#RequestHeader) :

```
<Location "/cas">
        RequestHeader edit Cookie "^(.*?)\|utmccn=.*?(\|.*)$" $1$2
</Location>
```