# Delete cookie based on url and referrer

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, apache2

Is it possible to delete a **specific cookie** via Apache if a **certain page** request contains a **specific referrer**?

I have found a similar question which is about deleting cookies in general ([How to remove a cookie in Apache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1798431/how-to-remove-a-cookie-in-apache)) but this does not use any conditions or cookie names.

My concrete use case is: Delete (or unset it's value) cookie named "country" if requested url is "/choose-language" and referrer is "www.external.domain".

Currently the following Apache modules are available:

```
core mod_so mod_watchdog http_core mod_log_config mod_logio     
mod_version mod_unixd mod_access_compat mod_alias mod_auth_basic 
mod_authn_core mod_authn_file mod_authz_core mod_authz_host 
mod_authz_user mod_autoindex mod_deflate mod_dir mod_env mod_expires 
mod_filter mod_headers mod_mime prefork mod_negotiation mod_php7 
mod_proxy mod_proxy_fcgi mod_remoteip mod_rewrite mod_setenvif 
mod_socache_shmcb mod_ssl mod_status
```

Comment: You can't delete http cookie using mod-rewrite but you can update or override value of a cookie but I don't think this is what you are looking for.  I think you should use  a PHP solution as its much better easier than mod-rewrite for manipulating HTTP cookie .

Comment: @starkeen Resetting the cookie value to "" would be enough in my case. Any suggestions/examples?

Answer (score 3):

Something like the below should do it:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} "^www\.external\.domain$"
RewriteRule "/choose-language" - [E=SetCookie:1]

Header set Set-Cookie cookieName= ENV=SetCookie
```

Use `mod_rewrite` to set an environment variable, then use it with `mod_headers` to modify the relevant header.

This example sends a `Set-Cookie` header to set `cookieName` to an empty value. I don't know what your upstream application is doing, so this may not be the correct configuration, but using either `Header unset` or `Header merge` in place of `Header set` should yield the correct result. More information [here](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_headers.html#header).

The most important section is using the `RewriteCond` and `RewriteRule` directives to set the environment variable `SetCookie`. Once you have this, it should be straightforward to figure out the correct response to remove or overwrite the cookie.

Answer (score 3):

Your loaded modules imply Apache 2.4 where you have access to `<If>` and conditional expressions on `Header`

```
<If "%{HTTP_REFERER} =~ /www.external.domain/ && %{REQUEST_URI} == '/choose-language'">
  Header add Set-Cookie country=
</If>
```

or

```
Header add Set-Cookie country= "expr=%{HTTP_REFERER} =~ /www.external.domain/ && %{REQUEST_URI} == '/choose-language'"
```